# toggle/visible check wrong behavior or a bug in the library

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a section on which I call toggle() with the callback format.
What I have noticed is that if I do a visible check on a child element of the toggled section, that is always the opposite. Instead of visible I get false.

I have the following code fragments:

```
$('.section_advanced').toggle('fast',resizeSection()); 

function resizeSection() {
    console.log($('#responsibilityLevel').is(':visible'));
    if ($('#responsibilityLevel').is(':visible')) { 
    } else {        
    }
}
```

where responsibilityLevel is child of of the .section_advanced section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `resizeSection` function instead of calling it.

This:

```
$('.section_advanced').toggle('fast',resizeSection());
```

should be:

```
$('.section_advanced').toggle('fast',resizeSection);
```